# CATiledLayer basics: Why is CATiledLayer's drawLayer:inContext: called so often when rendering PDFs?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-graphics, catiledlayer

I'm trying to understand how `CATiledLayer` works when rendering a PDF page using `CGContextDrawPDFPage()`.

My understanding was that `drawLayer:inContext:` is called once per tile and level of detail. Is that correct?

In the delegate of my tiled layer I call `CGContextDrawPDFPage().` 
However I noticed (by putting logs into the `drawLayer:inContext:`) that `drawLayer:inContext:` gets called more often if I make the tile size of my tiled layer smaller.
This makes me wonder:

- Is my PDF page drawn/rendered x times?
- Or does CGContextDrawPDFPage() magically know what part of the page to draw?
- Isn't CATiledLayer a waste of resources when rendering a PDF page? What is its advantage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I noticed that `drawLayer:inContext:` gets called more often if I make the tile size of my tiled layer smaller.

Yes, of course.  Assuming your layer's size is the same, then if you tell it to use smaller tiles, it will need more tiles to cover the area.

> Is my PDF page drawn/rendered x times?

Since you call CGContextDrawPDFPage() once per tile, then yes.

However, that may not be a problem, because:

> Does CGContextDrawPDFPage() magically know what part of the page to draw?

It might, but it doesn't require any magic.

Before CATiledLayer calls `-drawLayer:inContext:`, it sets the clip of the CGContext to include only the area of that tile. The PDF drawing code can get the clip bounds (via [`CGContextGetClipBoundingBox`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextGetClipBoundingBox)) and then choose to render only the content inside that rectangle.

That said, there are two caveats:

1. `CGContextDrawPDFPage()` is a black box, so it might not actually do that optimization. It seems obvious, but you'll have to check the performance numbers to see if it really is happening or not.
2. There is still considerable overhead in parsing and laying out the PDF content. You may still incur some of that cost on each call to `CGContextDrawPDFPage` -- it really depends on how smart CG is, and whether it caches things internally or not.

> Isn't CATiledLayer a waste of resources when rendering a PDF page? What is its advantage?

The advantage of CATiledLayer is mostly in memory savings: the bitmaps that rendered content are stored in are very large, so it pays to render and keep only the content that is currently visible on screen. It also provides a mechanism for caching the areas that were recently visible or might become visible again soon, depending on how the user zooms and scrolls.

The tradeoff is: you have to separate your drawing into separate calls for each tile, and you may have to render into tiles more often than you would have otherwise.

Depending on how large your view is, how far you zoom in/out, how expensive your PDF is to draw, and what else is happening in your application, it might make sense to use CATiledLayer or it might not. It's up to you to look at the performance numbers and decide.

Comment: I see. Thanks for shedding some light on this topic. I'm hoping, Apple will add more documentation and API here one day. Especially they seem to be able to support text selection now when viewing PDFs in Safari but the API is not exposed. Maybe if that comes, the documentation will be updated to.

Comment: If there is additional documentation you'd like to see on this topic, suggest it to Apple, either by filing a bug or by using the "Did this document help you?" button on the web-based documentation. Be specific about what docs you think are missing, because they can't read your mind.

Comment: I just ran into this today looking at the https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html sample code, it seems in TitledPDFView, it fills a rectangle the entire size of the scroll view (which is incorrect, it should only fill in the area that is represented by the context's bounding box), and then it just calls CGContextDrawPDFPage, without mentioning what partof the pdf page to show. I know it has the context, but its still not clear if CGContextDrawPDFPage is smart enough to only render that area, or the entire pdf centered on that area, etc

Comment: One way to reduce the overhead, is to set the tile size such that never more than 4 tiles are needed to cover the exposed screen area.

Answer (score 1):

Because Ogres... Ahem, PDF's are like onions.  QuartzCore is *Heavily* based around PDF rendering methods (so much so that the early documentation for it even mention this fact), and CATiledLayer uses the specific "tiling" render method, which specifies an object to be drawn repeatedly.  So, when the tile is moved or updated or whatever, the layer demands more data and so calls drawLayer:inContext: in one or more background threads.

CATiledLayers are also extremely efficient because they make heavy use of caching and only load visible layers.